# Why do bundelers like rollupjs or webpack import and inject CSS-files direct in JS?

Tags: webpack, rollupjs

I noticed that bundelers like webpack or rollupjs, respectively the corresponding pulgins, have this default behavior, that for bundeling CSS, one has to "import" the CSS files in JS.
Those CSS files will be injected into the JS.

I wonder why.
Is this just to have everything in one file?
Or is it just that you have one entry point for the bundler?
Is this now common practice?

- [example rollup](https://github.com/Anidetrix/rollup-plugin-styles#usage)
- [example webpack](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#getting-started)

I am not saying that CSS should not be bundled, I am wondering why it is bundled with JS.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not necessary to `import` CSS, you can do it with the traditional `<link />` element.
2. We `import` CSS because bundlers can then manage it as dependency which means we can do a lot of other things, e.g., use `autoprefixer`, `sass`, etc.
3. Most of those examples are for development environment, we don't extract them as there's overhead extracting CSS from JavaScript. But generally we do extract them into separate CSS files for production, for instance, using [`mini-css-extract-plugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) to extract CSS.

Comment: But I guess all the CSS processing like `autoprefix` would also work when included via `<link>`-element, right? I would just need to have the CSS as a separated entry point or I would need to have the html as entry point.

Comment: I don't think so. But if you do have an example, please share with me. Tools like webpack/rollup are built for specific use cases (mostly single page application IMO), if you don't write SPA, you might not need them, try to find alternatives.